# Run Powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I need to start a powershell script from C# and get the PSSSecurityException on pipeline.Invoke()

> AuthorizationManager check failed.

My code:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    Command scriptCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Questions

1. I suspect that I need to set PSCredential. But I can not promt for it, so I have to handle this in code. Can this be done in a secure way? (**This was not the case**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the script was placed on a share. To run scripts on this share I needed to add the share to Trusted Sites.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out this SuperUser post: https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts

You probably just need to allow unsigned scripts to run. In the PS console, type the following:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Another resource echoes this: http://tgnp.me/2011/09/powershell-authorizationmanager-check-failed-resolution/

Give that a try and let me know what happens.

To capture the output from the script, try this:

```
Collection output = pipeline.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
{
    <here you can ToString the psObject for the output and write it line by line to your log>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I could use the part about printing the output, the part about "AuthorizationManager check failed." was related to another problem with my environment. I have figured it out now and will post the solution for others that run into the same problem.