# Invoking powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to invoke previously made powershell scripts from a c# wpf GUI

I have found instructions on how to include the correct references, so I do have the `System.Management.Automation`
I have attempted multiple different Invokes and I have confirmed the powershell file works when run directly from PowerShell. I am using a test file that is simply `Add-Content -Path "C:\Test.txt" -Value "It Worked!"`

I have tried to specify the file location using the full path and the relative.

I have confirmed that in C# I can make the button close the window, so I know the issue is related to invoking the powershell.

I have also tried `BeginInvoke()`

```
    private void Btn_WU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@". .\Scripts\Test.ps1").Invoke();
        }

    }
```

I just want the invoked PowerShell file to create a file in C: at this moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Powershell from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855037/run-powershell-from-c-sharp)

Comment: No I have tested with Default, ByPass and Unrestricted and all have had the exact same result

Comment: `PowerShellInstance.AddScript` accepts a string, being the literal script.  You've told `AddScript` that the actual script text is `..\Scripts\Test.ps1` by accident, I believe.  See the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=pscore-6.2.0) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be closer to a working version:

```
private void Btn_WU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        var scriptContent = File.ReadAllText(@"full\path\to\your\script.ps1");
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptContent).Invoke();
    }
}
```